# Save Checked Boxes C#

Tags: c#, forms

Hi I have a form I'm making where the person can check boxes to see which items they've already read.  How do I save the checked boxes without going through some massive loop for each checkbox?  (there are 66 boxes total).

Comment: Do a `foreach (CheckBox child in parent.Controls)` and do something for each one that is not null.

Comment: I messed around with that...the problem is I don't know how to "do something" for each that is not null.  My thought was just sending the checked boxes to a list on a txt file and then on formload reading from the file and checking the boxes that were checked the previous session.  Not sure if that's the smartest idea or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't serialize forms. If you had a class running behind that tracked when check boxes where checked or unchecked you could serialize that. Then deserialize it to reconstruct the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the checkboxes elegantly with Linq:

```
var checkBoxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

foreach (var chk in checkBoxes)
{
    // Save state
}
```

One simple way to save state would be to place the checked state in a `Dictionary<string, bool>` using the control name as the key.  Serialize the dictionary to a file.

So,

```
// Save state
```

could look something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> state = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

var checkBoxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

foreach (var chk in checkBoxes)
{
    if (!state.ContainsKey(chk.Name))
    {
        state.Add(chk.Name, chk.Checked);
    }
    else 
    {
        state[chk.Name] = chk.Checked;
    }
}
```

Then, just serialize `state` using your favorite serializer that supports generic dictionaries.

Comment: It's even a bit nicer with a Dictionary extension method I wrote `AddOrSet(key, value)`.  Moves the `if` statement to see if the dictionary has the key already into the extension method.

Comment: Ok I'm trying your code so far I"m using: 

    `List<string> boxes = new List<string>();

var checkBoxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

            foreach(string s in boxes)
            {
                foreach (var chk in checkBoxes)
                {
                    if (s == chk.Name)
                    {
                        chk.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }

var checkBoxes = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

            foreach (var chk in checkBoxes)
            {
                boxes.Add(chk.Name);
            }`

Answer (score 2):

Fleshing out the comment that I made, assuming all of the checkbox are on the one control (either the Form or a Panel), that I have called 'parent'.

```
    foreach (CheckBox child in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (child == null) // Skip children that are not Checkboxes
          continue;
        // Save the child Checkbox
    }
```

Comment: You can also do `parent.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()`

Comment: No used singular checkboxes...like checkBox1, checkBox2, etc.  I didn't use a checkbox list.  I actually just read about that now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CheckedListbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx). And by using the [CheckedListBox.CheckedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) property you can only get the checked items.

```
private void WhatIsChecked_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // Display in a message box all the items that are checked.

    // First show the index and check state of all selected items.
    foreach(int indexChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices) {
        // The indexChecked variable contains the index of the item.
        MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() + ", is checked. Checked state is:" +
                        checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked).ToString() + ".");
    }

    // Next show the object title and check state for each item selected.
    foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {

        // Use the IndexOf method to get the index of an item.
        MessageBox.Show("Item with title: \"" + itemChecked.ToString() + 
                        "\", is checked. Checked state is: " + 
                        checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked)).ToString() + ".");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the CheckBox's `CheckedChanged` event and update your local variables( or Lists) accordingly. That way you will always know `CheckState` of each checkbox and you dont have to iterate everytime.

```
    CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
    box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(box_CheckedChanged);

    // Event Handler
    void box_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
            bool checkState = cb.Checked;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps...!!